# Get all the defined functions for an object

Tags: php, reflection, function

Is there an equivalent of [`get_defined_functions()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-functions.php) which only shows the functions of a given object?

Example usage and output:

```
class A {
    function foo() { }
    function bar() { }
}
class B extends A {
    function foobar() { }
}
$b = new B();
print_r(get_object_functions($b));

// Array (
//  0 => "foo",
//  1 => "bar",
//  2 => "foobar"
//)
```

Answer (score 20):

Ah I found it:

[`get_class_methods()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php)

Comment: NOTE: this will get instance methods too, not just class methods. I got confused by this.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`ReflectionClass`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php)...